# Macro with multiple "if" scenarios

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2007, I am trying to do everything with one macro.  Which is a combination of multiple `if`'s.

`If E147="ESM7" And C147="Bot" Then` the value shown in "O150", if not, then the value shown in "Q150".

But `If E147="ESU7" Then` the value shown in "O151", if not, then the value shown in "Q151".

So, there are 4 if scenarios, beginning with the main cell is "ESM7" or "ESU7" ,then depending if the next cell value is either a "Bot" or "SLD".

Comment: What's the question? I didn't see any interrogative point here...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What part of your code isn't working?  It would help if you actually included the code into the question, so that we can help you fix it.  (And why does it need to be in a macro, why not just write an Excel formula?)

Comment: Why do you need a macro? Can't you just put a few `IF` formulas in Q150 and Q151?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a coder and do not know how to write the formula and need your help.

Comment: We can help but we need more details. We cannot determine formulas without knowing all the cases. What if C147 != "Bot" and E147 = "ESM7" as example ? We need each condition and maybe you will have a clean answer...

Comment: In Cell I148 to return value based on the two if questions stated below.
The main if, is ESM7 or ESU7.
The next if, is BOT or SLD.


=IF(E147="ESM7",IF(C147="BOT",O150,Q150))

=IF(E147="ESU7",IF(C147="BOT",O151,Q151))

I am working with this code and it involves two macros.
Trying to get both codes into one macro.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vancouvertrader have you tried my code in my answer below ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Select Case` for these scenarios, also allows more flexibility in the future:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()

Select Case Range("E147").Value
    Case "ESM7"
        If Range("C147").Value = "Bot" Then
            Range("O150").Value = Val
        Else
            Range("Q150").Value = Val
        End If

    Case "ESU7"
        Range("O151").Value = Val

    Case Else
        Range("Q151").Value = Val

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not know how to put "Select Case" into the Visual Basic Editor.

Comment: All I know is how to get "Sub" into the Editor.

Comment: @vancouvertrader there is no difference, just copy this code section into yours and try it.

Comment: When I copy and paste your answer into the editor, and try to assign it to a macro button, I cannot select it, because it does not show up in the editor for me to choose it.

Comment: @vancouvertrader copy it inside the `Sub` you applied your button to

Comment: Can you get your answer in a "Sub" format. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vancouvertrader try now, change `Test1` to the name you have

Answer (score 0):

```
 val = 'value you want
 If Range("E147").Value = "ESM7" And Range("C147").Value = "Bot" Then
   Range("O150").Value = val
 Else
   If Range("E147").Value = "ESU7" Then
     Range("Q151").Value =val
   Else
     Range("Q150").Value = val
   End If


 End If
```

Comment: I tryed to copy and paste your answer, but got a "False" in Cell I148

Comment: Here is what I copied.

Comment: Sub ESM7ESU7()

    Range("I148").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(R[-1]C[-5]=""esm7"",IF(R[-1]C[-6]=""bot"",R[2]C[6],) else R[3]C[6])"
    Range("I148").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(R[-1]C[-5]=""esm7"",IF(R[-1]C[-6]=""bot"",R[2]C[6],) (else, R[3]C[6]))"
    Range("A147").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D135").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("F134").Select
End Sub

Comment: cell I145, did not return "False, but returned #NAME?'.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the CHOOSE function.

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/choose.php

Alternatively, take a look at the LOOKUP function.

http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Vlookup.html

You may find that it is easier to use that, rather than multiple IF statements, if you start to get overwhelmed with too many IFs.